# How to save a String in local buffer so that it can be re-read by Scanner?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am working on some project which deals with HTML pages.
I don't want to download the same page over and over again, so I want to save it locally.
I use the `Scanner` a lot, however the `Scanner` need a `InputStreamReader`.
For now I managed to save the HTML page to a local `StringBuffer`, however I can't make
this `StringBuffer` be used with the `Scanner`.

Can I make this `StringBuffer` be used as an `InputStreamReader`? If not, then what method can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has a [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.Readable%29) taking a [`Readable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html). Of all `Readable` implementations, the [`CharBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) seems to suit your purpose the most since you want to have a readable and writeable source.

```
String string = getItSomehow();
CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(string);
// ...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(buffer);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(new StringBuffer().toString().getBytes()));
```

If you want to do this right, you should send the `HTTP GET` request anyway, using the `If-Modified-Since` header, in order to correctly detect a page that has been changed.

Have you considered using a proper HTTP proxy though? That would save you the hassle of re-inventing the wheel in your application. An HTTP proxy would probably perform better and it would be usable by more than a single application.